# Cómo hacer llamada a Cloud SQL y pintar los datos en Google Spreadsheet

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo, jdbc, google-cloud-platform

estoy intentando crear un script en una hoja de cálculo para hacer una llamada a mi base de datos de SQL Cloud y pintar todos los datos.
El caso es que sólo he conseguido que se pinten los datos de la última fila de la BD en una celda concreta, pero no logro pintar todos los de la tabla.

¿Cómo podría hacer esta llamada para pintarlos en spreadsheet?

Os adjunto el código de mi script actual:

```
function recoger_datos5() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);

  var start = new Date();
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  stmt.setMaxRows(1000);
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM entries');
  var numCols = results.getMetaData().getColumnCount();

  while (results.next()) {
    var rowString = '';
    i= 7;
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
      rowString += results.getString(col + 1) + ', \t';
      var valor = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange("D" +i).setValue(rowString);
    }
    Logger.log(rowString);
  }

  results.close();
  stmt.close();

  var end = new Date();
  Logger.log('Time elapsed: %sms', end - start);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problema resuelto:** Esta sobre-escribiendo los valores en la misma celda, simplemente tenía que cambiar de celda cada vez que se ejecute el bucle. Para ello he sacado la variable i fuera del bucle y la incremento cada vez que éste se ejecute.

Comment: Agrega el código con el cual corregiste el problema, puede ser de ayuda a otro desarrollador , revisa [answer].